# Is the quote "Your mind is software. Program it. Your body is a shell. Change it. Death is a disease. Cure it." attributable to Peter Thiel?

Tags: quotes

The source is in [this tweet by Tim Ferriss](https://twitter.com/tferriss/status/510105263521939456?lang=en) dated Sep 10, 2014. I've listened to the podcast referenced there ([correct link](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/ep-28-peter-thiel-billionaire-investor-and-company/id863897795?i=1000318738557)) and searched the transcript of [that podcast on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pCIvOx76p0), but couldn't find any of those six sentences.

Another "source" is this [Australia Business Insider article](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/peter-thiel-quotes-2014-1), which points to the source of that quote being Blake Masters's [Notes from Peter Thiel’s CS183: Startup](https://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup) 2012 class at Stanford, but couldn't find any advice to program your mind there either.

Answer (score 113):

**No:** This is ¾ of the/a slogan of/blurb for the tabletop RPG *Eclipse Phase*, **not** a quote from Peter Thiel.  *Eclipse Phase* describes itself as “the post-apocalyptic game of transhuman horror”.  The full quote is

> - Your mind is software. Program it.
> - Your body is a shell. Change it.
> - Death is a disease. Cure it.
> - Extinction is approaching. Fight it.

You can see the quote on [the page for the first edition of the game, from 2009](https://eclipsephase.com/releases/eclipse-phase-core-rulebook); you can see that this goes back to the release of the book by looking back in the Wayback Machine and finding [the August 26, 2008 version of their page advertising the core rulebook book back when it was not yet released](https://web.archive.org/web/20080826062321/http://eclipsephase.com/upcoming-books).

---

This quote also **did not** previously originate with Peter Thiel.  While one can’t prove a negative, the evidence points to the following sequence of events:

1. Blake Masters takes a course with Peter Thiel in (northern hemisphere) Spring 2012 at Stanford and [publishes his notes](https://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup) on the class on his blog.
2. Blake Masters’s blog, [at the time](https://web.archive.org/web/20120417173457/http://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup), used the *Eclipse Phase* quote as an unsourced epigraph in the masthead.
3. On or around April 3, 2012, [John Chew](http://csinvesting.org/about) assembles [a partial PDF of Masters’s notes](http://csinvesting.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/blake-masters-start-up-notes.pdf) and includes the unsourced *Eclipse Phase* quote between Masters’s name and the link to Masters’s blog post which links to the notes.
4. Business Insider misunderstands Masters’s blog or Chew’s PDF thereof and attributes the quote to Peter Thiel in very similar listicles published on January 30, 2014 on [Business Insider India](https://www.businessinsider.in/tech/13-quotes-that-show-why-libertarian-tech-billionaire-peter-thiel-is-a-scary-genius/slidelist/29584815.cms) and [Business Insider Australia](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/peter-thiel-quotes-2014-1) (the latter of which is currently broken).
5. The quote and the incorrect attribution spread from there.

Here’s the evidence.  Per Google, [there are no references online to this quote colocated with Thiel’s name prior to January 1, 2012](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2012), besides a note on [the TVTropes page for *Eclipse Phase*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TabletopGame/EclipsePhase) (which contains the quote) that *Eclipse Phase* contains a character named “Petra Thiel”.  ([If I include “Peter” in the search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22peter+thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2012), I also get an [“Ask Ubuntu” page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gpu) that’s picked up a link to this question.  I won’t mention Stack Exchange links in what follows; during the duration of this research, even the time-bound results have changed as Google indexes Stack Exchange pages that point to this page.)

[Extending the search through January 1, 2013](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2013) explains the reference you found to Blake Masters’s CS183 notes: We find [a PDF](http://csinvesting.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/blake-masters-start-up-notes.pdf) from April 3, 2012 (per Google and per the date in the PDF) of some of the notes from said Blake Masters on the class (CS183: Startup) he took from Peter Thiel at Stanford in Spring 2012.  The PDF is *not from Masters*, however; it’s Masters’s notes collected by [John Chew](http://csinvesting.org/about).  The PDF starts with the full four-part *Eclipse Phase* quote, unsourced, between Masters’s name and [a link to a page on Masters’s tumblr](https://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup), which contains links to the same notes without the *Eclipse Phase* quote.  If we look back in time, we can see that at least between [April 17, 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120417173457/http://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup) and [November 11, 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20121111210410/http://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup), Masters’s blog used the full *Eclipse Phase* quote, unsourced, as part of the masthead on every page; this is potentially the source for the quote in Chew’s PDF.  [After November 11 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20130112202547/http://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup), Masters got the domain `blakemasters.com` instead of `blakemasters.tumblr.com`, and [excluded his site from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2/http://blakemasters.com); Masters’s website returns to `tumblr.com` in the Wayback Machine on [July 12, 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210712135040/https://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup), when it looks identical to today’s version without the quote.  As of now, Masters’s tumblr page links to more notes than the PDF; the PDF only links to the notes for classes 1–5, whereas the tumblr page has notes for classes 1–19.  Given the April date, this is probably because the PDF was assembled before the notes were complete; however, the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120417173457/http://blakemasters.tumblr.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup) version of the notes from April 17, 2012 only includes classes 1–4, so the timing presented here is probably not accurate down to the “day” level of granularity.

[Extending the search through January 1, 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2013) adds no more results, but [extending it one more month, through Feburary 1, 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A2%2F1%2F2014), finds the first explicit connections between the *Eclipse Phase* quote and Peter Thiel: there are now two more results, very similar Business Insider listicles published on January 30, 2014 on [Business Insider India](https://www.businessinsider.in/tech/13-quotes-that-show-why-libertarian-tech-billionaire-peter-thiel-is-a-scary-genius/slidelist/29584815.cms) and [Business Insider Australia](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/peter-thiel-quotes-2014-1) (the latter of which is currently broken).  They both attribute the full (four-part) *Eclipse Phase* quote to Peter Thiel.  They source it to Masters’s blog during the period where it was off Tumblr (`http://blakemasters.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup`, which [now redirects to the page we were looking at above](http://blakemasters.com/peter-thiels-cs183-startup)), so we cannot examine the exact contents; however, as we see above, there are two plausible paths for associating the *Eclipse Phase* quote with the course notes, either from the blog’s masthead (if the quote was still present) or Chew’s PDF.

After this, the association of the *Eclipse Phase* quote with Thiel begins to spread, although still with all four parts and mostly not as something directly attributed to Thiel.  [Extending the search four more months, through June 1, 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A6%2F1%2F2014), finds [the archive of a blog by Hervé Lebret](https://www.startup-book.com/2014/03/) which refers to the full *Eclipse Phase* quote as “the sentence which comes at the top of each series of class notes”, not as something by Thiel in particular.  [Extending the search four more months, through October 1, 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A10%2F1%2F2014), finds [a September 23, 2014 blog post by Joshua Berk](https://berk.is/blogging/distributed-productivity) that attributes the *Eclipse Phase* quote to Peter Thiel in the blog’s sidebar; it’s not clear when this quote was added, as the page is not in the Wayback Machine.  [Extending through November 1, 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A11%2F1%2F2014), we get a reference which cites the quote correctly: [a blog post from October 4, 2014, by L.M. Sacasas](https://thefrailestthing.com/2014/10/04/our-very-own-francis-bacon/) cites the *Eclipse Phase* quote as “that tag line on Masters’ website”.

[Running the search for 2015](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015) gives three results: [an image incorrectly attributing the full *Eclipse Phase* quote to Peter Thiel](http://www.picturequotes.com/your-mind-is-software-program-it-your-body-is-a-shell-change-it-death-is-a-disease-cure-it-quote-222774); and two versions, [the official web page](https://harpers.org/archive/2015/01/come-with-us-if-you-want-to-live/) and [an unofficial PDF](https://www.hedweb.com/social-media/apocalyptic-libertarians.pdf), of a Harper’s article entitled “Come With Us If You Want to Live: Among the apocalyptic libertarians of Silicon Valley”, by Sam Frank, which describes the *Eclipse Phase* quote as Masters’s “motto” which comes from “a science-fiction role-playing game”, and mentions it after talking about Masters’s Tumblr.

[From 2016 on](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thiel%22+%22your+mind+is+software%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A), we mostly see random references to the quote that *are* incorrectly attributed to Peter Thiel, typically in lists of quotes or as one-off comments, with a few exceptions (not to mention the many Stack Exchange pages that mention this question): [Blake Masters’s “Talent Bureau” page](https://talentbureau.com/speaker/blake-masters/) features the abbreviated quote in some sort of “tagline”-like position, and does not attribute it; [a Reddit comment by /u/gynoidgearhead](https://www.reddit.com/r/YouShouldKnow/comments/9omfp3/ysk_that_the_vast_majority_of_human_deaths_92_are/e7xe0ys/) cites the full quote as “[*Eclipse Phase*](http://eclipsephase.com) tag line (later cribbed by Peter Thiel)”; and of course, [this question itself](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52240/has-peter-thiel-said-your-mind-is-software-program-it-your-body-is-a-shell-c), which by now has gone into some detail on why the *Eclipse Phase* quote is just that, and *not* due to Peter Thiel :-)

---

Some extra context about *Eclipse Phase*, to help see why the quote might have become connected to Peter Thiel: *Eclipse Phase* describes itself, as mentioned above, as “the post-apocalyptic game of transhuman horror”, and involves player characters with separate stats for their mind and body (“ego” and “morph”), hence the first two points; they are part of a conspiracy to protect humanity, hence the fourth point.  The third point is thematically linked, as mind uploading allows for cheating death and genetic engineering is omnipresent in the setting.  As the first three points are broadly transhumanist, and Peter Thiel is ([per Wikipedia’s categorization scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Thiel)) at least something of a transhumanist, this could be the reason for people’s enduring belief in the spurious connection.

Comment: @Schmuddi we can't prove a negative. so unless somebody provides a previous source, we can assume this originates from Eclipse Phase

Comment: I've gone through and documented the earliest uses of this quote and how it gradually became associated with Peter Thiel.  (Also, I would like to point out that the original citation was from a published book that predates any claim that Thiel said this, so that plus the existence of things like copyright already provided a strong backing for the original stance.)

Comment: wow. to say "this answer is useful" is quite an understatement... good job!

Comment: Thanks for the extensive edit – I withdraw any objection! :)

Comment: In the context of "not proving a negative" the existence of this "Petra Thiel" character is a bit bothersome. Can we *really* be sure that the Eclipse Phase authors were not friends or admirers of Peter Thiel and were aware of his undocumented invention of the quote, choosing to feature both the quote in their game and a nod to their regard for him by naming a character, either in direct connection to the quote or a separate mark of respect?!

Comment: @Will Considering the authors are fairly far-left, it would be highly surprising that they would admirers of an arch-capitalist. But then again... can't prove a negative.

Comment: @JSLavertu okay, maybe not admirers then but fascinated by him as a malevolent figure. It would be strange for them to have been so directly acquainted with his words if he really had said them first though. Either Blake Masters has to have plagiarized the quote from Thiel's unpublished words separately, or lifted it unironically (since the game seems to use the quote for dystopian effect) from the game, which might have referenced Thiel independently and separately from Masters' own kinship with Thiel.

Comment: @Will: This suggestion commits the error of allowing the claim to prejudice your conclusions.  There are many characters in Eclipse Phase; you could ask that question about any of them with a name similar to a real person.  The only reason you've chosen Peter Thiel is because of connections to him that show up _after_ publication that are then asked about here – and because this question mentioned his name.  But we shouldn't let the question smuggle the answer in through the back door like that!  There's no more reason to mention Peter Thiel in association with the quote than anybody else.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky I'm not saying that the theory proves that the claim in the question is true. I'm saying that the circumstantial evidence that it is false is also consistent with a scenario where it's true; in other words, the fact that this answer cannot prove a negative should not be overlooked or underestimated.

Comment: Indeed, the principal evidence we are dealing with is the fact that Thiel's name on the quote once appeared in the same vicinity despite no indication of the two being deliberately connected. The co-occurrence within the game is exactly that too. Everything else is a subjective evaluation of which is the bigger coincidence.

Comment: @Will: The only reason you've chosen Thiel is because the question asked about him – the same argument applies to anybody referenced in _Eclipse Phase_. We could equally well say it's possible that Lady Gaga originated the quote, since there's a character named after her. Or Edgar Allen Poe, since there's a character named Nevermore. Your mention of Thiel instead of anybody else is _only_ because this question asks about him, which is circular. If you hadn't cherry-picked just him in your comment, I might not have objected. But nobody has ever linked this quote to Thiel via a source.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to prove a negative; this quote could've originated with anybody from Shakespeare to Ursula K. Le Guin. But that's true of any other quote in English too. We don't continue to insist that the first person to say "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit." could've been CS Lewis, not JRR Tolkien, just because they knew each other. He could've been, yes – there's no way to prove otherwise – but this isn't a justifiable claim. Likewise, continuing to insist that this quote might have come from _Thiel specifically_ even without evidence isn't skepticism, it's contrarianism.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky you can say that no evidence exists to support attributing Thiel specifically in a far shorter answer. I'm specifically addressing your preferred explanation for why Business Insider believed the quote was Thiel's. This explanation is based on a colocation of words that is just as specific and selected from circular reasoning as any inference drawn from the two features of *Eclipse Phase*. I'm not saying either are right, just that the existence of both requires caution when stretching that far in explaining the claim.

Comment: Aditionally, one of the authors of Eclipse Phase has explicitely stated that the quote originated from them (in a reply to the original tweet).

Comment: @JSLavertu here is [the tweet where Eclipse Phase creators claim that they originated the quote](https://twitter.com/adamjury/status/1430622718941143047?s=20). Its author, Adam Jury-Last, is not listed on [the Drive-Thru RPG page](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/284022?affiliate_id=77000&src=wtep) as an author. However, he is the co-owner of Posthuman studios according to [their about page](https://posthumanstudios.com/about-posthuman-studios).

Comment: Very meta! What's the policy on referencing key parties who verify that circumstantially-sourced answers on this site are correct?

Answer (score 9):

There is precedent for the first three lines that predate the game, *Eclipse Phase* mentioned in [Antal Spector-Zabusky's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/47419/antal-spector-zabusky). A clever game designer put them together to fit their game concept.

### Your mind is software

Found this book chapter from 1994: 'The Mind as the Software of the Brain' ([An Invitation to Cognitive Science](https://www.nyu.edu/gsas/dept/philo/faculty/block/), edited by D. Osherson, L. Gleitman, S. Kosslyn, E. Smith and S. Sternberg, MIT Press, 1995) written by Ned Block from NYU.

### The body is a shell

This is the title of a [1956 movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050202/).

### Death is a disease:

Clint Mansell produced a song titled *[The Fountain (death is a disease)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVq5Vy5Gw3U)*.

### Extinction is coming

Appears to be unique to Eclipse Phase.

Comment: @Oddthinking: thanks for the clean up.